# Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 8.1.1, failed version requirement: >=9.0.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

My initial issue began setting up push notification and trying to capture the device token. I kept getting an error stating that the FCM plugin isn't installed so I uninstalled and reinstalled everything and noticed the following while installing the FCM plugin again.

```js
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.3.0
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.3.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 8.1.1, failed version requirement: >=9.0.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated' for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" for ios
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 8.1.1, failed version requirement: >=9.0.0
```

so I uninstalled Cordova and installed 9.0.

cordova -v
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

It's clearly version 9 but I'm still getting this error and I'm not sure why it still thinks I'm using 8.1.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.